# Compiling of Protouf file in aix getting failed

Tags: linux, aix, protobuf-c

I am trying to compile **protobuf** in Aix machine, during **make** giving me given below error

```
/usr/bin/as -u -mpwr4 -many -o ../src/VistaraAgent/build/Debug/AIX/net/AgentProtoBufData.pb.o /tmp//ccsfEtju.s
Assembler:
/tmp//ccsfEtju.s: line 4122: 1252-142 Syntax error.
/tmp//ccsfEtju.s: line 4124: 1252-142 Syntax error.
Makefile:116: recipe for target '../src/VistaraAgent/build/Debug/AIX/net/AgentProtoBufData.pb.o' failed
gmake: *** [../src/VistaraAgent/build/Debug/AIX/net/AgentProtoBufData.pb.o] 
Error 1
```

please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/google/protobuf

Comment: Well, it requires some 'gmock-1.7.0'; I found something called 'googlemock-master', but it seems to have other dependecies (`aclocal: error: configure.ac:1: file 'gtest/m4/acx_pthread.m4' does not exist`) I give it up for now